# How long can sfdx refresh sobject definitions run?

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, visualstudiocode

I have a dev sandbox against which I am pulling a SFDX: Refresh SObject Definitions. It has been almost 24 hours since I have initiated this and it is still running. The sandbox has a lot of objects but is this expected to be still running? How can I check the status? Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: SFDX CLI commands will definitely not run for this long. Few things to generally try out when you run into problems with SFDX CLI. Have to tried to cancel it and re-authorize the org (before running it again)? Have you tried installing latest updates for SFDX CLI and VS Code? In your SFDX project folder, go to subfolder `.sfdx\tools\sobjects` and check if any Sobject definition has been refreshed at all?